# create sign up form by combining symfony2 and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

i want to create a sign up form by using symfony2 and ajax

here is my controller:

```
 public function registerAction(){

    $request = new Request(
        $_GET,
        $_POST,
        array(),
        $_COOKIE,
        $_FILES,
        $_SERVER
    );

    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new UserType(),$user);

    $res = array();
    if( $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid() ){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render( 'tgBundle:Default:register.html.twig',array( 'form' =>$form->createView() ) ) ;

}
```

and the script code :

```
$(function(){
$('form[name="tgbundle_user"]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : the_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : $('form[name="tgbundle_user"]').serialize(),
        dataType : 'html'
        }
    }).done(function(data){        
        $('mydiv').html(data);
    });
});
});
```

And this code worked .

but my problem is when i click in the button to submit more than 2 times the navigator refresh the whole page after the ajax request is done.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to achieve.. May be you should add some jquery code which disables the button while request is being sent?

Comment: what i want is that just the form inside "mydiv" change without refreshing the whole page, i used "e.preventDefault();" for that , but it didn't work
and i used "return false;" it didn't work either

Comment: i think maybe the problem is from php.